# how to add record in alphabetical order

Tags: perl, file

A    File contains (a.txt)

```
# this is test file 

Data: 15th may 2010 

Records :

a  

b

c 

d

g

l
```

> just consider if i want to add new record  "f" - i want addit in betwen  d and g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::File) and treat the text file as array. This example assumes that there're no blank lines and initial text:

```
use Tie::File;
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', 'filename' or die $!;

my $rec = 'f';

for my $i (0..$#array) {
    if (($array[$i] cmp $rec) == 1) {
        splice @array, $i, 0, $rec;
        last 
    }
}
```

Comment: my file has empty lines and there are some blank lines .

Comment: @SCNCN2010: You can add this test to the loop: `next if $array[$i] =~ /^\s+$/;`

Answer (score 1):

in one line:

```
perl -le 'print for(sort((map {chomp; $_} (<>)), "f"))' < infile > outfile
```

You obviously need to process the headers beforehand, but the technique is pretty clear

For example:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ perl -le 'print for(sort((map {chomp; $_;} (<>)), "f"))' <<EOP
> x 
> v
> b
> m
> p
> o
> l
> j
> k
> EOP
b
f
j
k
l
m
o
p
v
x
[dsm@localhost:~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Tie::File ();
use List::MoreUtils qw(lastidx);

my $new_item = 'f';
{
    my @file;
    tie @file, 'Tie::File', 'a.txt'
        or die "Could not open 'a.txt' for reading: $!";
    splice @file, (1 + lastidx { $_ lt $new_item } @file), 0, $new_item;
}
```